# Read array of objects from file by custom separator

Tags: c++

I have model class for my objects:

```
class customClass {
 string s1;
 string s2;
 string s3;
}
```

and file like this:

```
text1;text1;text1 text1 text1...
text2;text2;text2 text2 text2...
...
```

and I want make array of objects where

```
s1 = "text1"
s2 = "text1"
s3 = "text1 text1 text1..."
    ...
```

My code:

```
infile.open("file.txt");
if (infile.is_open())
{
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        infile >> line;
        stringstream ss(line);
        while (ss.good())
        {
            string substring;
            getline(ss, substring, ';');
            cout << substring <<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

But it separated every single word. How can I ignore whitespaces to make my 3rd string as text not as single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesnt work for you is because `infile >> line;` will read up to the first space character instead of the whole line (this is when you need `getline`). Maybe something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream outfile("file.txt");
    outfile <<

R"(text1;text1;text1 text1 text1...
text2;text2;text2 text2 text2...)";

    outfile.close();

    // read file

    std::ifstream infile("file.txt");
    std::string par1, par2, par3;
    while (std::getline(infile, par1, ';') && std::getline(infile, par2, ';') && std::getline(infile, par3))
        std::cout << par1 << " | " << par2 << " | " << par3 << std::endl;
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=eb52001b5d4ecbed

Comment: Thanks for your replay! I tried your solution but it didn't work, there is an output: (sorry for format but in comments I cant do it in single lines)
(line1)text1;text1;text1
(2)ext1
(3)ext1
(4)text2;text2;text2
(5)ext2
(6)ext2 text2
(7)text3;text3;text3
(8)ext3
(9)ext3 text3 text3

Answer (score 0):

Just don't read single string at the begining, also I added the loop until the end of file, so your code would look like:

```
std::ifstream infile("file.txt");
std::string line;

if (infile.is_open())
{
    string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        string substring;
        while (getline(ss, substring, ';')) {
           cout << substring <<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read all line with `getline` function. Default `>>` operation get values until `\n`,  (space) character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class CustomClass
{
  public:
    string s1;
    string s2;
    string s3;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("test.txt");

    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            string line;
            getline(infile, line);
            stringstream ss(line);

            CustomClass cls;
            getline(ss, cls.s1, ';');
            getline(ss, cls.s2, ';');
            getline(ss, cls.s3, ';');

            cout << cls.s1 << " - " << cls.s2 << " - " << cls.s3 << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```